# What does this napari and pyQT5 installation and compatibility error means?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I am experiencing a compatibility issue with napari and pyqt5, is there anything I can do to make this work? I updated the pyqt5 version I have, but it take more than 4 hours already... and there is no much progress...

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.data import astronaut
import napari

with napari.gui_qt():
    viewer = napari.view_image(astronaut(), rgb=True)
```

```sh
/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/napari/__init__.py:44: UserWarning: 
    napari was tested with QT library `>=5.12.3`.
    The version installed is 5.9.6. Please report any issues with this
    specific QT version at https://github.com/Napari/napari/issues.
    
  warn(message=warn_message)
```

Comment: Are you using a conda environment? Have you tried to uninstall pyqt5 and use the PySide2 backend?

Comment: Yes, I used conda for the jupyter notebook.

Comment: I do not know why, but anaconda comes with the very old version of QT. This message which you provide shows that it still uses PyQt5 5.9.6 which is a build one. Are you sure that you update PyQt5?

Comment: which conda channel was used for install? 

```conda create -y -n napari-env -c conda-forge python=3.9
conda activate napari-env```

the recommended instructions for install are above - I would confirm that napari was installed using the ```conda-forge``` channel